# Symfony: Asset Component and .scss files

Tags: symfony, sass

I have been reading about the new [Asset Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/asset/introduction.html#component-assets-path-package). It seems very interesting and useful (as some people [say](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component) :)). Since it seems it is not "recommended" to use Assetic any more, how should we filter `.scss` files to get `.css` files using this new component? I couldn't find any information about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Symfony 2.8 and later no longer includes Assetic by default, you can still [install and enable it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) if you'd like to. (Basically: add `symfony/assetic-bundle` to your `composer.json` and add the necessary configuration.)

The [best practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) these days is to use frontend tools specifically focused for frontend development. (The Symfony best practices document specifically recommends GruntJS, but it's not the only solution.)